# What can be the cause if DNSSEC suddenly stops working and normal resolving is extremely slow viua unbound?

Tags: dns, ipv6, unbound

Suddenly, every .com domain failed DNSSEC validation (regardless of it is signed or not), and normal resolving fails randomly with DNSSEC disabled, for example all youtube videos say "A error occured".
Manually resolving urls with dig or nslookup randomly gets a SERVFAIL when DNSSEC is off, else it Always get a SERVFAIL.

Here is the log with DNSSEC enabled: http://pastebin.com/9maHnk6L

Here is the log with DNSSEC disabled: http://pastebin.com/yVjMe9CU

What could be the cause of these problems? Theres no problems with the upstream ISP Connection, I checked Everything. Is there some root server issue?

Im running dual-stack with IPv6 from he.net

Is there some global internet issue or is the problem at my side?

Answer (score 0):

if you just resign it, does everything start working again? I had the same problem, but i resign the domain and magically it starts working again. This happens about every 30 days. From what I am reading you're supposed to resign once every 30 days.